# Multi-project failed to build in Gradle-4.2.1

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, multi-project

I am migrating my project to use Multi-project structure . Currently I am using Gradle-4.2.1. When I configure the gradle throws below exception

Exception:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not normalize path for file 'D:\User\Project2:Subproject1'.

  > The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 0s

My project structure

-root
    -Project1 
    -build.gradle

```
-buildProject
-build.gradle
-settings.gradle 

-Project2 
-build.gradle
    -Subproject1
    -build.gradle
    -Subproject2
    -build.gradle

-Project3
-build.gradle
```

Below is the settings.gradle looks like

includeFlat 'Project1'
includeFlat 'Project2'
includeFlat 'Project2:Subproject1'
includeFlat 'Project2:Subproject2'
includeFlat 'Project3'

I have below questions.

Am I am using correct gradle version (supports multi-project structure)?
Is My project structure correct?
Any other changes needed to in the settings.gradle to build the project successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `include "Project2:Subproject1"`, not `includeFlat`, in order to include nested subprojects. If you read the official documentazion [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html), you can read

*The includeFlat method takes directory names as an argument. **These directories need to exist as siblings of the root project directory.** The location of these directories are considered as child projects of the root project in the multi-project tree*

`include` works fine with nested subprojects:

*The project path is assumed to be equal to the relative physical file system path. For example, a path 'services:api' is mapped by default to a folder 'services/api'*

I hope this can help you to solve the problem!

Comment: Yes, I have used **include ** in settings.gradle and it works fine. Thanks for your reply.